# where do I find the app to open the cytoscape download file?

Tags: download, cytoscape

hello I am using a personal computer and it is not clear which app is required to access the downloaded file available on the STRING app website. I appreciate your help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so you can install Cytoscape from: https://cytoscape.org and install the stringApp: https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/stringapp